# Tablet devices loading wrong orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

My app only uses one page which is the main activity and in the manifest it is set not to allow rotation hence the orientation stays the same wether or not you rotate the device. however on tablets when a user is in landscape orientation and runs the app. the app loads the default orientation (Portrait) but in a landscape view instead and im seeing only half the screen.
help.
This is part of my activity in manifest i use nosensor to disable rotation.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.paul.xicon.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how are you disabling the screen rotation. But this should work just fine in your activity tag of manifest.

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape" (disables the screen-rotation & restricts to landscape mode)

or,

android:screenOrientation="portrait" (disables the screen-rotation & restricts to portrait mode)
```

Comment: In AndroidManifest.xml inside <activity